# How to move scrollview upward in autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

In Signup page , I have many text fields in UIScrollVoew , so like other app i want to move Scroll upward once textfields at bottom are tapped , but i am not sure that old way which were using will work or not ? can any body please help what is best way of moving scroll automatically using autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom class to autoScrolling click on last Textfield . [Check it](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

You can define outlets in your code and set their sizes for your need. Something like this.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewBottomConst;

self.textViewBottomConst.constant = height;
```